# Flutter: response on http post returns empty

Tags: android, http, flutter, post

I'm trying to get the response after making a post to an api, but the response (which is a json) doesnt come, when i try to print the line is empty.
Can someone help me to figure out what i'm making wrong?

I have printed the status code just for testing and its returning 500, could this be related?

```
Future<void> _login() async {
    Map<String, dynamic> newLogin = Map(); 
    newLogin["user"] = _usuarioController.text.trimLeft();
    newLogin["pass"] = _senhaController.text.trimLeft();

    Map<String, String> headers = new Map<String, String>();
    headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json";

    int timeout = 2;

    http.Response response = await http
        .post('https://sistema.hutransportes.com.br/api/login.php',
            headers: headers, body: jsonEncode(newLogin), encoding: utf8)
        .timeout(Duration(seconds: timeout));

    print(newLogin);
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body); //Where the empty response comes
}
```

Comment: 1) Increase the timeout (I don't think you get a result within 2 seconds in real-world scenarios. For testing set it to at-least 20) 2) 500 is internal server error. So something is broken at your server side

Comment: Your server doesn't appear to require a json body in the POST, but regular x-www-form-urlencoded. Equally, it doesn't seem to return JSON. (It returned "ok" with a dummy user password.) Have you confirmed a test request with Postman?

Comment: @MidhunMP 1 - Did it, thanks. 2 - I'm trying to solve but the guy on the server says its ok.

Comment: @RichardHeap The guy on the server has changed the response to test, before he was sendind a json and the result was the same (empty response). And yes, i tested on postman and works normally, only on flutter the response comes empty (maybe because of the statuscode 500, i dont know)

Comment: @abrev In postman what was the content-type ? What was the status code you got ?

Comment: It was a json, but now just a "ok". The status on postman is 200.

Comment: @abrev did you later got answer to this?